# Button click changes visibility of a DataGrid with a Trigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

Hi i am trying to find some way to when a button is clicked changes the visibility of other control, like a DataGrid with a Trigger in XAML.

The button only changes the visibility of the DataGrid to Visible, it does other things in Code Behind, but this is something that i think that can be done in a Style with a Trigger.

I tried to find a solution and it seems to be possible to do but i can't understand how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Button!">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference dataGrid}"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

`{x:Reference dataGrid}` references a DataGrid with the name `dataGrid`, alternatively you could just use `Storyboard.TargetName`. You would normally use the `Storyboard.Target` property if you do binding or references to resources.

Comment: You outrun me.. I was just about to post the same.. :)

Comment: But in think instead of adding the namespace 'pc' in markup extension. I'll use this - <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />

Comment: Happens a lot to me too, gotta be quick! That about the visibility is interesting, didn't know it was accessible that way already.

Comment: I was just wondering what if we want to toggle the control visibility on the button click. Won't it be good if we use the ToggleButton and play with its "IsChecked" property to toggle instead of using EventTrigger??

Comment: The checkable solution is covered by Damascus already, i wanted to specifically answer the question that was asked (which is obviously more complicated)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! But i have another question related to it. Can we do this no to change the visibility of a control, but to open another window in the application?

Comment: That would involve a method call if the window needs to be created, you could create a property which will do that call if it is set to true, that way you could use an animation as well. I would not suggest you do that though. A command-binding would be more appropriate in that case i think. Other than that you could create the window when the application starts but do not show it, then you could animate the window visibility like this as well.

Comment: I probably will use a method to do it. About a thing related to the main question. If i want to change anything in another controls when the Enable state of other control occurs, i really have to use the TriggerEvent or i can do it with a simple Trigger? For example we have a button that is enabled and we have other controls disabled, if the button is disabled, can we enable the other controls with a Trigger?

Comment: I would probably use a `DataTrigger` with binding for that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but how about, for something more understandable, having a Checkbox enabling/disabling the DataGrid display? This is what I usually do:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="DisplayBox"
                      Content="Display grid" Margin="4" IsChecked="False"/>
   <DataGrid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DisplayBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</DockPanel>
```

And of course, you'll have to implement the appropriate converter

Comment: No need for implementation, such a converter exists in the framework already actually, it's called `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that and continued using a converter I've done long time ago. I will consider removing it now!

Comment: Same here, was pretty much the first converter i wrote, cannot remember when i found out about the existing one though.