# How can I display a TextBlock only after pressing a button?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to display a screen Texblock, only after pressing the button. If I do a simple code as well, the text is always displayed instead. How do I hide it? I have to work in the code behind?

```
<Button Content="Inizia" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="145,78,0,0" Click="Inizia"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,155,0,0">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Width="360">
                <TextBlock Text="Vedo nuvole in viaggio 
                                 che hanno la forma delle cose che cambiano, 
                                 mi viene un po' di coraggio 
                                 se penso che le cose poi non rimangono mai " Height="331" Width="361" FontSize="16"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Basicly You need to add a Name for Your TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextbox" Visibility="Hidden" Click="button_click"/>
```

And then in Your eventhandler for button click event:

```
button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTextbox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the xaml set the `Visibility` property of your `Textbox` to `Hidden` or `Collapsed`

in the buttons click event set the it to `Visible`, you will need to add a `Name` to the `Textbox` so you can access it in the code behind

Difference between `Collapsed`and `Hidden`:
if you set it to `Collapsed` it won't be visible and won't take any space either
if you choose for `Hidden` it won't be visible but will still take in space

To do it in the xaml reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663494/1498624) on a different post

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s a example on how to do it in the code behind